# Why is pip asking me to upgrade when it's already up-to-date?

Tags: python, python-3.x, installation, pip, upgrade

I have a brand new installation of python 3.7.1 64-bit and I'm using the latest pyCharm as my IDE. I have no other installation of python on this machine.

I go to install numpy and I get this message:

```
(venv) C:\Users\John\PycharmProjects\project>pip install numpy
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\users\john\pycharmprojects\pysims\venv\lib\site-packages (1.15.4)
You are using pip version 10.0.1, however version 18.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

So I run the suggested command but it's already up-to-date

```
(venv) C:\Users\John\PycharmProjects\project>python -m pip install --upgrade pip
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in c:\users\john\pycharmprojects\pysims\venv\lib\site-packages (18.1)
```

So I check the version but it's still the old version

```
(venv) C:\Users\John\PycharmProjects\pySIMS>pip -V
pip 10.0.1 from c:\users\john\pycharmprojects\pysims\venv\lib\site-packages\pip-10.0.1-py3.7.egg\pip (python 3.7)
```

I thought I'd try py -3 to upgrade and it works.

```
(venv) C:\Users\John\PycharmProjects\pySIMS>py -3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
Collecting pip
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c2/d7/90f34cb0d83a6c5631cf71dfe64cc1054598c843a92b400e55675cc2ac37/pip-18.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: pip
  Found existing installation: pip 10.0.1
    Uninstalling pip-10.0.1:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-10.0.1
Successfully installed pip-18.1
```

But the version is still old

```
(venv) C:\Users\John\PycharmProjects\pySIMS>pip -V
pip 10.0.1 from c:\users\john\pycharmprojects\pysims\venv\lib\site-packages\pip-10.0.1-py3.7.egg\pip (python 3.7)
```

WHAT IS GOING ON? Am I missing something totally obvious? I've never had an issue like this working in Python 2 but since I've moved to Python 3 it's been nothing but errors.

Answer (score 6):

This is looking like you have multiple installation of pip, one that comes first in the PATH (pip) and another that is recognized by python (python -m pip).
Try running the command:

```
pip show pip
```

and

```
python -m pip show pip
```

And check if the path are the same.
If not i would suggest uninstalling the undesired one, or change your your PATH environment variable to have the folder containing the correct pip come before the folder with the wrong one.

Comment: Thanks. What I ended up doing is cd into the directory of my python installation with the out of date pip, cd into 'Scripts', then run the upgrade command. That way it found pip in the current directory first and upgraded it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

When I got this error I had 2 pip version folders in **site-packages**. One **pip-19.2.3.dist-info** and another something like **pip-10.0.1**. I deleted the first one, leaving only the default version. Then running `python -m pip install --upgrade pip` fixed the problem

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where I was upgrading pip; however, my issue what that I had a pip.conf file that pointed to a repo that didn't have the version to upgrade to.  I removed the pip.conf to allow it to go to the default repo and it was able to download the correct version and upgrade.

Answer (score -1):

1.Open you project setting(File>Settings)
2.Project>Project Interpreter
3.find pip and lick the triangle on the right(in the red circle I draw)
[image]